# Algorithm for finding the SumKSmallest

Tags: python, algorithm

Can anyone help me solve this question in pseudocode?
Consider the function SumKSmallest(A[0..n − 1], k) that returns the sum of the k smallest elements in an unsorted integer array A of size n. For example, given the array A =[6,-6,3,2,1,2,0,4,3,5] and k =3, the function should return -5.
a. Write an algorithm in pseudocode for SumKSmallest using the brute force paradigm. Indicate and justify (within a few sentences) the time complexity of your algorithm.b. Write another algorithm in pseudocode for SumKSmalleast using the transform & conquer paradigm. Your algorithm should strictly run in O(n log n) time. Justify the time complexity of your algorithm. c. Explain with details, how we could implement another SumKSmalleast that strictly runs in less than O(n log n) time, considering k<

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: I have written the steps using Brute force approach
1) apply selection for 3 times if k =3 
2) Find 1st 3 smallest elements if k= 3
3) Add all first 3 smallest element, you will find sum of the k smallest element in an unsorted array
4) Time complexity = if k=1 , n time
if k =2 ,2n times
if k =3, 3n times
if k = n, n^2 times
So, the worst-case time complexity is O(n^2)
As I am totally new to pseudocode, I am not able to write in pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

Brute force 
O(n^2) You got it right.

Second Approach:
Sort the array and sum the first k numbers to get the sum of the smallest K numbers. `O(nlog(n))` Merge Sort.

Third Approach:
Heap: Take the first K elements and Max-heapify it. Now iterate over remaining elements taking them one by one and comparing it with the root of max-heap (arr[0]), if (arr[0] > element) remove arr[0] from the heap and add an element into heap. At last, you will be left with K smallest numbers of the array. 
`O(k + (n-k)log(k))`

Read about Min-heap and Max-heap

Comment: Is this code correct for pseudocode of a. ?
function SumKSmallest(A(0..n-1],k)
   for i <- 1 to n-1 do
       minpos <- i
       for j <- i+1 to n do
           if A[j] < A[minpos] then
               minpos <- j
       swap A[i] and A[minpos]

Comment: for i (1 to n-1)
     for j ( i+1 to n)
         if(A[i] > A[j] )  swap (A[i], A[j])
Now your array will be sorted.

Comment: which sorting method have you used for bubble sort?